# converting a string into a data frame name

Tags: r

In functions such as `plotmeans` there is an argument that specifies the data frame to use, `data=`.  I would like to construct the name of the data frame to be used using `paste0` or something similar, `df <- paste0("results", i)`, where i is a number to get (say) "results04".  If I then use `data=df`, I get an error saying that `data=` expects a variable, not a string.  Is there any way to convert the string into a form that `data=` will accept? `data=results04` without the quotes, of course, works.

Thanks for any suggestions or pointers.

Answer (score 8):

The answer would have been obvious to one with more R experience, but let me put it here for others: use the `get()` function, so for instance

```
df <- paste0("results", i)
plotmeans(a ~ b, data=get(df))
```